# Asynchronous Task error in doInBackground method

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

**I have try this code**

```
public class Splashscreen extends Activity {
String urls = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    try {
        new MyTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        RSSFeed_SAXParser saxParser = new RSSFeed_SAXParser(urls);
        Log.i("ClearBef", "----------------Cache-Clear-----------");

        Log.v("getTitleList", "="+saxParser.getTitleList().size());
        Log.v("getImageUrllist", "="+saxParser.getImageUrllist().size());
        Log.v("getDurationList", "="+saxParser.getDurationList().size());
        Log.v("getVideoUrllist", "="+saxParser.getVideoUrllist().size());
        Log.v("getBitrateUrllist", "="+saxParser.getBitrateUrllist().size());
        Log.v("getGuidlist", "="+saxParser.getGuidlist().size());
        Log.d("getPubDateList", "="+saxParser.getPubDateList().size());
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);

                // overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }, 100);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
  }
 }
```

**//--------------------------**

```
 public class RSSFeed_SAXParser extends Activity {
String streamTitle = "";
ArrayList<String> mediaUrlList, imageUrlList, guidList, titleList,
        pubDateList, bitrateList, durationList;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public RSSFeed_SAXParser(String url) {
    mediaUrlList = new ArrayList<String>();
    imageUrlList = new ArrayList<String>();
    guidList = new ArrayList<String>();
    titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    bitrateList = new ArrayList<String>();
    durationList = new ArrayList<String>();
    pubDateList = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        URL rssUrl = new URL(url);
        SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory
                .newInstance();
        SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();

        RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
        myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
        InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
        myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private boolean item = false;
    private boolean title = false;
    private boolean guid = false;
    private boolean image = false;
    private boolean pubdate = false;
    private boolean media = false;
    int count = 0;
    long bitr = 0;
    String url, duration, bitrate;
    String imageUrlValue, guidValue, titleValue, pubDateValue;
    private boolean flagTitle = false,  flagImage = false, flagMedia = false;

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equals("item")) {
            item = true;
            count++;
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("content") && item) {
            int w = 0;
            long bit = 0;
            try {
                w = Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("width"));
                bit = Long.parseLong(attributes.getValue("bitrate"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (1024 <= w && bit > 1100000) {
                bitrate = attributes.getValue("bitrate");
                url = attributes.getValue("url");
                duration = attributes.getValue("duration");
                Log.v("videoWidth" + localName,
                        "=" + attributes.getValue("width"));
                flagMedia = true;
            }else if( w == 640 && bit > bitr && !flagMedia){
                bitrate = attributes.getValue("bitrate");
                url = attributes.getValue("url");
                duration = attributes.getValue("duration");
                Log.v("640videoWidth" + localName,
                        "=" + attributes.getValue("width"));
            }
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("thumbnail") && item
                && !flagImage) {
            image = true;
            flagImage = true;
            Log.v("ImageAttributes" + localName,
                    "=" + attributes.getValue("url"));
            imageUrlValue = attributes.getValue("url");
            //imageUrlList.add(attributes.getValue("url"));
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("updated") && item) {
            pubdate = true;
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title") && item
                && !flagTitle) {
            title = true;
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("clipid") && item) {
            guid = true;
        } else {
            // Log.v("=" + localName, "=" + qName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equals("item")) {
            item = false;
            flagImage = false;
            flagTitle = false;
            // flagMedia = false;

            media = true;

            // flagMedia = true;
            Log.w("MediaAttributes" + guidValue, "===" + url);
            if(url != null)
            {
                mediaUrlList.add(url);
                bitrateList.add(bitrate);
                durationList.add((Integer.parseInt(duration)*1000)+"");
                guidList.add("Clip"+guidValue);
                titleList.add(titleValue);
                pubDateList.add(pubDateValue);
                imageUrlList.add(imageUrlValue);
            }
            flagMedia = false;
            bitr = 0;
            url = bitrate = duration = guidValue = titleValue = pubDateValue         = imageUrlValue = null;
            Log.v("=" + count, "=" + qName);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

        if (title && item) {
            title = false;
            flagTitle = true;
            Log.d("title=", "=" + new String(ch, start, length));
            //titleList.add(new String(ch, start, length));
            titleValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        } else if (guid && item) {
            guid = false;
            //guidList.add(new String(ch, start, length));
            Log.d("guid=", "=" + new String(ch, start, length));
            guidValue = new String(ch, start, length);
        } else if (image && item) {
            image = false;
            // Log.d("image=", "=" + new String(ch, start, length));
        } else if (pubdate && item) {
            pubdate = false;
            //pubDateList.add(new String(ch, start, length));
            pubDateValue = new String(ch, start, length);
            Log.d("pubdate=", "=" + new String(ch, start, length));
        } else if (media && item) {
            media = false;
            // Log.d("media=", "=" + new String(ch, start, length));
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> getTitleList() {
    return titleList;
}

public ArrayList<String> getPubDateList() {
    return pubDateList;
}

public ArrayList<String> getImageUrllist() {
    return imageUrlList;
}

public ArrayList<String> getGuidlist() {
    return guidList;
}

public ArrayList<String> getDurationList() {
    return durationList;
}

public ArrayList<String> getBitrateUrllist() {
    return bitrateList;
}

public ArrayList<String> getVideoUrllist() {
    return mediaUrlList;
}

}
```

Please Let Me Know what i am doing wrong thanks in advance.

**Error i am getting is below**

```
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:197)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:111)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:780)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at com.fusioni.xmlParser.RSSFeed_SAXParser.<init>(RSSFeed_SAXParser.java:27)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at com.fusioni.spacealabama.Splashscreen$MyTask.doInBackground(Splashscreen.java:111)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at com.fusioni.spacealabama.Splashscreen$MyTask.doInBackground(Splashscreen.java:1)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 07:14:31.662: E/AndroidRuntime(16819):    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Well, I'd say you're doing nothing wrong. Yep, your program crashes just like it should. Could you please tell us your program's expected behavior?

Comment: Thanks for replay
If I write doInBackground method code in onPostExecute  method its working fine but my progressbar stop animating in case of post method.

Comment: I have solved this problem by calling HTTP request in doInBackground() and get Data Stream (input stream) and SAXParser in onPost method.

Answer (score 1):

Two major things wrong:

1. You cannot call `new` on an `Activity`.  They are created on demand by the system based on `Intent` objects.
2. You cannot create `Handler` objects (by way of the `new RSSHandler()` call) inside of an `AsyncTask`.  It is a temporary, short lived background processor run in an arbitrary thread.  A `Handler` requires a `Looper` which has been started and bound to a `Thread`'s running context.

Comment: Same code is Running properly If I write doInBackground method code in onPostExecute method its working fine but my progressbar stop animating in case of post method.

Comment: That's because `onPostExecute()` is run on the UI thread where `doInBackground()` is run in arbitrary thread context.  Regardless, you are creating a huge object unnecessarily (`RSSFeed_SAXParser` is an `Activity` but should not be.)  You might want to read this article to get a better understanding of `AsyncTask`: http://po.st/Cei3m2

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir... 
 i have resolved my problem another way by fetching data in background thread and then i parsed this in post method.